# Yii2 NOT IN condition not working

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, yii2-active-records

I use this for query not in:

```
 $usertypes=Usertype::find()->where(['not in ','user_type_id',['2,3,4']])->all();
```

Error:

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
```

Undefined offset: 1
Failed to prepare SQL: SELECT * FROM `usertype` WHERE `user_type_id` NOT IN :qp0

also tried the array format as ['2','3','4'] but not works?What is the issue?

Comment: remove space from `where(['not in',`

Comment: It looks like you already found the solution, but it's worth noting that you can negate a where condition like this: `->where(['not', ['user_type_id' => ['2', '3', '4']]])`.

Answer (score 25):

Try This :

```
$usertypes=Usertype::find()
           ->where(['not in','user_type_id',[2,3,4]])
           ->all();
```

OR :

```
$usertypes=Usertype::find()
               ->where(['NOT',['user_type_id'=>[2,3,4]]])
               ->all();
```

Refer : http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-model/#In-Condition

Comment: Got it! The problem in space after 'not in  '. Thanks @Yasin Your ref.link help me out a lot

Answer (score 2):

Maybe remove space character from `'not in '`?

```
$usertypes=Usertype::find()->where(['not in', 'user_type_id', ['2,3,4']])->all();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use "`not`" word or "`<>`"

```
 $usertypes=Usertype::find()->where(['not',['user_type_id'=>['2,3,4']]])->all();
```

or this

```
 $usertypes=Usertype::find()->where(['<>',['user_type_id'=>['2,3,4']]])->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `->andFilterWhere` instead of where `->where`

Try this:

```
$usertypes = Usertype::find()
           ->andFilterWhere(['NOT IN','user_type_id',[2,3,4]])
           ->all();
```